# shorthand syntax for c++ map in map

Tags: c++, dictionary

If I have definitions like:

```
typedef map<string, Foo> Foo_map_1
typedef map<string, Foo_map_1> Foo_map_2
typedef map<string, Foo_map_2> Foo_map_3
typedef map<string, Foo_map_3> Foo_map_4
typedef map<string, Foo_map_4> Foo_map_5
```

Is there anyway I can generalize that so I could do, for example,

```
Foo_map<10>
```

and have a 10-fold nested map. I don't need something like `boost::recursive_wrapper` because the number of levels is always constant.

Answer (score 20):

This is seems easy enough even for the limited C++ metaprogramming power:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

template<int N, typename K, typename V>
struct NMap { typedef std::map<K, typename NMap<N-1, K, V>::type> type; };

template<typename K, typename V>
struct NMap<1, K, V> { typedef std::map<K, V> type; };

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    NMap<3, int, std::string>::type m;
    m[1][2][3] = "Test";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind using 2 structures ?

Comment: @sameerkarjatkar: One is the generic template that maps an N-map into a map from key to a (N-1)-map. The other is the template specialization that ends the recursion for the N=1 case (otherwise the template recursion would be infinite). The structure is needed because C++03 has no "template typedef" and the standard workaround to do this kind of type computation is to use a template structure that contains only a typedef.

Comment: IOW, if your compiler is moderately up-to-date you don't need those structures anymore.

Comment: @MSalters: the C++03 limitation is not important (only requires you to add `::type`). OTOH c++11 aliases (that as far as I can tell are the "solution") do not allow partial specialization and that seems to me a more serious problem.

Comment: @6502: Well, you can alias partial specializations but you can't partially specialize aliases. So you can definitely alias your `NMap<N,K,V>::type`. But you also have `std::conditional<std::string, typename std::map<N-1, K, V>, (N==1)>::type` which can replace that partial specialization.

Comment: @MSalters: did you ever ask yourself why that `::type` at the end of `std::contitional`?

Comment: No, that's pretty obvious. It's a direct descendant of `boost::conditional` ;)

Answer (score 11):

This works for me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

struct Foo
{
   Foo() : _in(0) {}
   Foo(int in) : _in(in) {}
   int _in;
};

template <int N> struct Foo_map
{
   map<string, Foo_map<N-1> > foo_Map;
   Foo_map<N-1>& operator[](string const& key) { return foo_Map[key]; }
};

template <> struct Foo_map<1>
{
   map<string, Foo> foo_Map;
   Foo& operator[](string const& key) { return foo_Map[key]; }
};

int main()
{
   Foo_map<1> map1;
   map1["abcd"] = Foo(10);

   Foo_map<2> map2;
   map2["a"]["b"] = Foo(20);

   Foo_map<10> map10;
   map10["a"]["b"]["c"]["d"]["e"]["f"]["g"]["h"]["i"]["j"] = Foo(100);

   std::cout << map1["abcd"]._in << std::endl;
   std::cout << map2["a"]["b"]._in << std::endl;
   std::cout << map10["a"]["b"]["c"]["d"]["e"]["f"]["g"]["h"]["i"]["j"]._in << std::endl;
}
```

The output of running the program:

```
10
20
100
```