# c++11 variadic programming, how to define a tower of vectors

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming, c++14

How (if possible) can I use c++11 variadic programming to define a series of `vector`'s in a function body, (or in other words, a sequence of `N`-dimensional arrays with decreasing `N`'s until 0), like the variables below?

```
vector<vector<vector<int>>> v<3>;
vector<vector<int>> v<2>;
vector<int> v<1>;
int v<0>;
```

What I imagined is something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<int ...> struct seq {};
template<int N, int ...S> struct gens : gens<N-1, N-1, S...> {};
template<int ...S> struct gens<0, S...>{ typedef seq<S...> type; };

template<int ...S>
void f(seq<S...>) {
  //how do I write definitions of v<N> here?
  vector<vector<...(N layers)<vector<int> ...> v<N>;     //??how-to, not valid c++
  vector<vector<...(N -1 layers)<vector<int> ...> v<N-1>;//??how-to, not valid c++
  //...
  vector<int> v<1>;  //??how-to, not valid c++
  int v<0>;          //??how-to, not valid c++

  //...
}

int main() {
  f(typename gens<3>);
  return 0;
}
```

Also, would this be easier in c++14?

Thanks,

--EDIT--

Just to clarify, what I mean by "a tower of vectors" is best described by a N-tuple (v_1, v_2, ..., v_N), where N is an integral template parameter. v_1 is of vector, v_2 is of vector>, and so on.

--EDIT2--

So far, quantdev and R's answers have successfully solved the problem of defining a N-tuple for any fixed N, like 3, but cannot generate a tuple for an unspecified `N`. In addition to the functionality in the answers, I need a function which can be used like `gen_tower<N>` that returns `tuple(v1,v2,...,vN)`.

Consider the example of using variadic programming to compute factorials. I need a function to compute factorial `factorial<N>()` for any `N`, in addition to the ability to write out any specific expression `<1*2*3>` manually. (That was the reason why I asked about variadic programming and whether `c++14` will make it easier.)

P.S.

Purely out of personal interests, I want this sequence to hopefully implement a generic function that can read a N-dimensional array from file. I don't know exactly how yet, but I think at step one, I should be able to define the final `N`-dimensional array, and the intermediate `k`-dimensional arrays for `k` from `N-1` to `1`. I can read 2-dimensional arrays, and 3-dimensionals. But it would be nice to be able to read arrays of any dimensions.

Comment: can you exemplify how you're intending to use these N arrays, or is it an exercise to define them?

Comment: @Alf, this is purely out of personal interests. please see the update in P.S. cheers.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is no need for variadics, a recursive `typedef` is sufficient to generate those types at compile time.

---

**How is is implemented ?**

**1)** Provide a template with 2 arguments : the vector elements type (`T`), and the desired dimension of the structure (`size_t N`). Declare a typedef `type` : it will be based on the declaration of `type` for the template instantiated with the depth `N-1`, hence the recursion.

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
struct VectorGenerator
{
    typedef std::vector< typename VectorGenerator<T, N-1>::type > type;
};
```

**2)** Provide a termination case for ending the recursion, here a specialization of our template with the dimension 0, declaring the type of a usual `std::vector<T>`.

```
template<typename T>
struct VectorGenerator<T, 0>
{
    typedef std::vector<T> type;
};
```

---

**How to use it ?**

We can now declare a vector `v` of type `VectorGenerator<T, N>::type` :

```
VectorGenerator<double, 4>::type v; // v as a depth of 4 and handle double
```

But it's not very readable or convenient, and pretty verbose. Let's introduce new names for our types.

This is the perfect case for [template aliasing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias), with the (C++11) `using` keyword for aliasing. We have 2 different ways of aliasing :

**1)** Declare an alias for a particular dimension and type, here we call it V3 for `N=3` and `T=double` :

```
using V3 = VectorGenerator<double, 3>::type;  // Alias

V3 v;                                         // Use the alias
```

Or,

**2)** Declare a template alias for a particular type, leaving the dimension as a template parameter:

```
template <size_t N> 
using V = typename VectorGenerator<double, N>::type;  // Alias

V<3> v;                                              // Use the Alias
```

---

**Final code sample:**

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
struct VectorGenerator
{
    typedef std::vector< typename VectorGenerator<T, N-1>::type > type;
};

template<typename T>
struct VectorGenerator<T, 0>
{
    typedef std::vector<T> type;
};

// Alias for V3, V2 ... usage
using V3 = VectorGenerator<double, 3>::type;
using V2 = VectorGenerator<double, 2>::type;

// Alias for V <k> usage
template <size_t N> 
using V = typename VectorGenerator<double, N>::type;

int main() {

    V<3> v3;
    V<2> v2;
    v3.push_back(v2);
    return 0;
}
```

---

**Notes :**

- Consider the [Boost MultiDimensional Array library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html).
- I am not sure of what your final goal is, but this might well be an overkill.
- As for your second edit, declaring a `tuple` with multiple vectors of different dimensions is now easy :

**Example:**

```
auto tower = std::tuple<V<1>, V<2>, V<3>>(v1, v2, v3);
```

For the generic tuple generation of multiple "towers", @mpark gave [a working **C++14** solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24471769/3510483), I adapt it here to my code sample:

```
template <typename T>
struct identity { using type = T; };

// Generate a tuple of towers by mapping index_sequence over gen_tower.
template <typename T, std::size_t... Is>
std::tuple<VectorGenerator<T, Is>...> gen_towers_impl(std::integer_sequence<Is...>);

// Make an index_sequence for N and use gen_towers_impl.
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct gen_towers
    : identity<decltype(gen_towers_impl<T>(std::make_index_sequence<N>()))> {};

// Convenience type aliases
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
using gen_towers_t = typename gen_towers<T, N>::type;
```

You will need `-std=c++1y` to compile it (and include `<utility>` and `<tuple>` headers)

See a working example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3076956eaee69baf).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and pointers for boost multidimensional array. Is there a way to write the results as something like v<3>, v<2>?? Please see my update.

Comment: What do you mean exactly ? its not clear to me. What you meant as "V<3>" is my V3, I guess. No ?

Comment: @TingL `template <size_t N> using V = VectorGenerator<double, N>;` `V<3> v;`

Comment: That is seriously clever. I know how to do that with macros, but I've never seen it done in templates before.

Comment: I'd follow the usual convention and change `::value` to `::type`, otherwise good answer.

Comment: @quantdev, I mean that I need not only to generate v1, v2 and v3, but also generate v_N for a parameter N. This is probably best described by a tuple. Please see my EDIT.

Comment: Well, you say that N is known at compile time, so just do `auto tower = std::tuple<V<1>, V<2>, V<3>>(v1, v2, v3);`, whats wrong with this ?

Comment: Personally, I would define `VectorGenerator<T, 1>` as the one-dimensional vector instead of `VectorGenerator<T, 0>`.

Answer (score 5):

You can find a similar question but dealing with `std::map` at [shorthand syntax for c++ map in map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23601686/shorthand-syntax-for-c-map-in-map/23601853#23601853).

Here's one for `std::vector`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<int N, typename V>
struct NVector { typedef std::vector<typename NVector<N-1, V>::type> type; };

template<typename V>
struct NVector<1, V> { typedef std::vector<V> type; };

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

   NVector<1, int>::type v1(10, 0);

   NVector<2, int>::type v2;
   v2.push_back(v1);

   NVector<3, int>::type v3;
   v3.push_back(v2);

   for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
   {
      std::cout << v3[0][0][i] << " ";
   }
   std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

**Update**

You can simplify the usage of these vectors with a `using` declaration.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<int N, typename V>
struct NVector { typedef std::vector<typename NVector<N-1, V>::type> type; };

template<typename V>
struct NVector<1, V> { typedef std::vector<V> type; };

template<int N, typename Val>
using V = typename NVector<N, Val>::type;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

   V<1, int> v1(10, 0);

   V<2, int> v2;
   v2.push_back(v1);

   V<3, int> v3;
   v3.push_back(v2);

   for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
   {
      std::cout << v3[0][0][i] << " ";
   }
   std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

If you want to make it still simplified by assuming the value type to be `int`, you can use:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<int N, typename V>
struct NVector { typedef std::vector<typename NVector<N-1, V>::type> type; };

template<typename V>
struct NVector<1, V> { typedef std::vector<V> type; };

template<int N>
using V = typename NVector<N, int>::type;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

   V<1> v1(10, 0);

   V<2> v2;
   v2.push_back(v1);

   V<3> v3;
   v3.push_back(v2);

   for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
   {
      std::cout << v3[0][0][i] << " ";
   }
   std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to define the results as something like v<3>, v<2>?? Please see my update.

Comment: @R Sahu. I think what I am really looking for is to generate a tuple of (v1, v2, ..., v_N) for a parameter N, or parameter pack (based on what you showed). Please see my EDIT. Thanks

Comment: @TingL, without looking at a use case, it's hard to suggest what you are looking for. I hope you have enough from the answers to run with it.

Answer (score 2):

I won't go into too much detail in generating a single tower since it's explained by other answers here. Here is my version of `gen_tower<T, I>` which generates a tower of vectors depth `I`.

For example, `gen_tower_t<int, 2>` is `std::vector<std::vector<T>>`.

```
// Useful for defining meta-functions compactly.
template <typename T>
struct identity { using type = T; };
```

#### gen_tower<T, I>

```
// Forward declaration.
template <typename T, std::size_t I>
struct gen_tower;

// Convenience type alias.
template <typename T, std::size_t I>
using gen_tower_t = typename gen_tower<T, I>::type;

// Base case.
template <typename T>
struct gen_tower<T, 0> : identity<T> {};

// Wrap std::vector around tower of depth I - 1.
template <typename T, std::size_t I>
struct gen_tower : identity<std::vector<gen_tower_t<T, I - 1>>> {};
```

#### gen_towers<T, N>

Now we can use `std::index_sequence` to define `N` towers.

```
// Generate a tuple of towers by mapping index_sequence over gen_tower.
template <typename T, std::size_t... Is>
std::tuple<gen_tower_t<T, Is>...> gen_towers_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>);

// Make an index_sequence for N and use gen_towers_impl.
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct gen_towers
    : identity<
          decltype(gen_towers_impl<T>(std::make_index_sequence<N>()))> {};

// Convenience type aliases
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
using gen_towers_t = typename gen_towers<T, N>::type;
```

#### Examples

```
static_assert(std::is_same<gen_tower_t<int, 0>, int>::value, "");

static_assert(std::is_same<
                  gen_tower_t<int, 2>,
                  std::vector<std::vector<int>>>::value, "");

static_assert(std::is_same<
                  gen_towers_t<int, 2>,
                  std::tuple<int, std::vector<int>>>::value, "");

static_assert(std::is_same<
                  gen_towers_t<int, 3>,
                  std::tuple<int,
                             std::vector<int>,
                             std::vector<std::vector<int>>>>::value, "");

int main() {}
```