# how to create and delete a new 2d vector of object pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm not sure if I'm doing this right, I feel like there should be a simpler way to do it. I'm trying to create a new two dimensional vector of objects in a constructor. my compiler seems to be ok with my code, but I want to be sure I'm not causing any memory leaks.

here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

//prototypes
class node;
class link;



class node
{
    public:

    vector<link*> links;

    ~node()
    {
        for(unsigned int i=0;i<links.size();i++) 
        {
            delete (links[i]);
        }
        links.clear();
    }
};


class link
{
    public:
    node &origin;
};



class network
{
    public:



    network( int dimensions[])
    {
        for (int i=0; i < (sizeof(dimensions)/sizeof(*dimensions)); i++)
        { 


            vector<node*> *nvec= new vector<node*>;


            for (int j=0; j <dimensions[i]; j++)
                {
                    (*nvec).push_back(new node);
                }

            layers.push_back(*nvec);

        }
    }

        //cleanup
        ~network()
        {

        for(row=layers.begin(); row!=layers.end(); row++)
    {

        for(col=row->begin(); col !=row->end(); col++)
        {
            delete(*col); //im hoping this deletes the node not the iterator
        }
        row->clear();//will this clear the row it points to ?
    }
    layers.clear();

        }


    private:
    vector<vector <node*>> layers;
    vector<node*>::iterator col;
    vector<vector<node*>>::iterator row;
};


int main()
{
    int arr[]={1,1,1};
    network net(arr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is almost never a good practice to new a vector. And you do not need to do this. 2-dimensional vectors do not exist, but you can use a vector of vectors.

Comment: Might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463356/c11-variadic-programming-how-to-define-a-tower-of-vectors.