# Elegantly define multi-dimensional array in modern C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, c++14, template-meta-programming

Defining multi-dimensional array using the `T[][][]` syntax is easy. However, this creates a raw array type which doesn't fit nicely into modern C++. That's why we have `std::array` since C++11. But the syntax to define a multi-dimensional array using `std::array` is quite messy. For example, to define a three-dimensional `int` array, you would have to write `std::array<std::array<std::array<int, 5>, 5>, 5>`. The syntax doesn't scale at all. I'm asking for a fix for this issue. Maybe, this issue cannot be fixed using existing utility provided by C++. In that case, I'm happy with a custom tool developed to ease the syntax.

Found a [solution](https://github.com/Lingxi-Li/CPP_Utility/blob/master/cppu/meta.hpp#L32) myself:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t n, std::size_t... ns>
struct multi_array {
  using type = std::array<typename multi_array<T, ns...>::type, n>;
};

template <typename T, std::size_t n>
struct multi_array<T, n> {
  using type = std::array<T, n>;
};

template <typename T, std::size_t... ns>
using multi_array_t = typename multi_array<T, ns...>::type;
```

Wondering whether the implementation can be further simplified.

Comment: @AngryLettuce I think that would be a little too heavy for simple matters like this. I don't want to pull in a whole Boost just for this.

Comment: Are `typedef`'s not acceptable: `typedef std::array< std::array< std::array<int, 5 > > > threeD;` .. `threeD arr; arr[0][0][0] ...`? This example would have to be modified to allow for different types, obviously, but curious if that might help?

Comment: You could use the approach in the answers of the question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463356/c11-variadic-programming-how-to-define-a-tower-of-vectors.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/q/7689288/636019 – the same question, but tagged `c++11`.

Comment: Note that the memory layout of a nested `std::array` isn't guaranteed to be the same as that of a C=style array of arrays (at least in C++11, I'm not sure if that got fixed in C++14.)

Comment: @juanchopanza Isn't `std::array` just a simple wrapper around raw array?

Comment: @Lingxi But the standard allows it to have some padding at the end (or at least it did in C++11.)

Comment: Main difficulty is access using indices.

Comment: @juanchopanza Nested std::array are stored in contiguous mem locations. See  https://stackoverflow.com/a/47121087/3820989

Comment: @MandeepSingh Yes. My comment still stands.

Comment: @juanchopanza Ah yes, you are right, read your comment again and you are not talking about contiguous mem location but probably about padding which might occur :)

Answer (score 13):

Refer to [Multi-dimensional arrays in C++11](http://cpptruths.blogspot.com/2011/10/multi-dimensional-arrays-in-c11.html)

```
template <class T, std::size_t I, std::size_t... J>
struct MultiDimArray 
{
  using Nested = typename MultiDimArray<T, J...>::type;
  // typedef typename MultiDimArray<T, J...>::type Nested;
  using type = std::array<Nested, I>;
  // typedef std::array<Nested, I> type;
};

template <class T, std::size_t I>
struct MultiDimArray<T, I> 
{
  using type = std::array<T, I>;
  // typedef std::array<T, I> type;
};

MultiDimArray<float, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7>::type floats;
```

`MultiDimArray` is a pair of meta-functions to compute nested type for multi-dimensional `std::array`. The most general `MultiDimArray` is a variadic template of unsigned integers to pass an arbitrary number of dimensions. The terminating `MultiDimArray` specialization defines the simplest case of single dimensional `std::array`.

Comment: Could the implementation be further simplified?

Comment: Its usage can be a tiny bit more improved by using template alias on top of it:
`template <class T, size_t I, size_t... J>
using MultiDimArray_t = typename MultiDimArray<T, I, J...>::type;

MultiDimArray_t<float, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7> floatArr;`