# C++ resizing a 4D stl vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have a 4D vector of following type:

`vector< vector< vector< vector< unsigned > > > > vec`
I don't know the size of the 4th dimension at the beginning, so I am trying to resize the first 3 dimension in the following way:

```
vec.resize(x.size(), vector< vector< vector< unsigned > > >
(y.size(), vector< vector< unsigned > >(2)));
```

where x and y are of type `vector<unsigned>`

After I resized the first 3 dimensions in the above way mentioned I can't access any element from dimension 3(i.e `vec[i][j][1]`).

Can anyone please suggest what am I missing here?

Comment: I think using `using` or `typedef` would simplify this a lot.

Comment: Why resize them? Why not create them the correct size, except for the 4th, and then resize that>

Comment: because this vector has to be global and I think I can only declare the size of a vector inside a function @NeilButterworth

Comment: "I think I can only declare the size of a vector inside a function" Nope. And I'm pretty sure it doesn't have to be global.

Comment: @FabiaBushraTamanna --  *I can't access any element from dimension 3* -- What error do you get?  A compiler error?  Runtime error?

Comment: Can I talk you into a nice, 1 dimensional vector with in a wrapper class that makes it look like a 4D array? Hell of a lot easier to use. Probably faster, too.

Comment: After applying somewhat sane `typedef`'s, [cannot duplicate](http://ideone.com/6V8a5n).  The code above accesses the 3 dimensions with no issue.  So is it a runtime error you're getting, and not something to do with syntax?

Comment: no I tried to insert element using vec[i][j][1].insert(). But no suggestion comes up, that means I couldn't allocate any space for that vector position @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: If you're going by IDE suggestions, change your code to `auto& v1 = vec[i][j][1];`.  Then call `v1.insert(whatever);`

Comment: This is a cache locality nightmare.  Until you know the 4th dimension, your structure cannot store any data, apart from a whole bunch of structure and pointers.  You're better off writing a simple class to keep your actual data in a single allocated block.  You can then use `std::valarray` or similar to interact with the data via whatever indexing methods you choose to provide.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35008089/elegantly-define-multi-dimensional-array-in-modern-c