# Does std::array of std::array have contiguous memory?

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, memory, allocation

Seems, that I found how to easily get normal 2D Array with contiguous memory in 2 lines of code:

```
template<int N, int M>
using Array2D = array<array<int, M>, N>;
```

Let's solve easy task of **swapping min and max** in `Array2D` (a little of c++17):

```
template<int N, int M>
void printArray2D(const Array2D<N, M> &arr);

int main() {
    const int N = 5;
    const int M = 5;
    Array2D<N, M> arr;

    // random init of Array2D 
    generate(arr.front().begin(), arr.back().end(), []()->int {
                                                        return rand() % 100;
                                                    });

    printArray2D(arr);

    auto[a, b] = minmax_element(arr.front().begin(), arr.back().end());

    cout << "Swap minimum and maximum: " << *a << " " << *b << endl << endl;

    iter_swap(a, b);
    printArray2D(arr);

    return 0;
}

template<int N, int M>
void printArray2D(const Array2D<N, M> &arr) {
    for (const auto &row : arr) {
        for (const auto &elem : row) {
            cout << std::setw(3) << elem;
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

I got next result in Visual Studio 2017:

```
 41 67 34  0 69

 24 78 58 62 64

  5 45 81 27 61

 91 95 42 27 36

 91  4  2 53 92

Swap minimum and maximum: 0 95

 41 67 34 95 69

 24 78 58 62 64

  5 45 81 27 61

 91  0 42 27 36

 91  4  2 53 92
```

Pros:

- Only 2 simple lines to get 2D array
- You can normally access elements as `arr[2][2]`
- You can use stl algorithms

Cons:

- This solution doesn't work normally in Debug mode, I've got runtime error `array iterators incompatible`
- I don't know if the memory always will be allocated contiguously
- I don't know if it works in other compilers
- Magic iterators

**Questions:**

- Is contiguous allocation for `Array2D` ensured by anything?
- Is it eligible to use array iterators in this way? (different iterators, but bear in mind contiguous and implementation on pointers)
- Is `Array2D` safe to use in this manner (as in example) in production code? If not, can you present good code for solving this task with minimum code overhead?
- [geza](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47120994/does-stdarray-of-stdarray-have-contiguous-memory#comment81192325_47121087): This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762662/is-the-data-in-nested-stdarrays-guaranteed-to-be-contiguous/9762712#9762712) contradicts to continuity of nested arrays. Maybe something has changed in C++14?

Comment: The memory would be contiguous, but in `generate(arr.front().begin(), arr.back().end()` you are using iterators into two different containers and *that*  is not allowed.

Comment: You are definitely not allowed to treat this as a continuous array of ints, but I'm pretty sure continuous memory layout is guaranteed.

Comment: @BoPersson, Yes, it is wrong in conception of iterators, but an `_Array_iterator` works over pointers, so it seems that this code unacceptable only because of iterator conception?

Comment: The memory is *contiguous* but the elements are not required to be (because of padding) so mixing iterators from different array elements is undefined behavior (as would be using the actual pointers).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the data in nested std::arrays guaranteed to be contiguous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762662/is-the-data-in-nested-stdarrays-guaranteed-to-be-contiguous)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the standard the memory should be contiguous. The [26.3.7.1 [array.overview]](http://eel.is/c++draft/array#overview-1) paragraph states (emphasis mine):

> The header  defines a class template for storing fixed-size
>   sequences of objects. An array is a **contiguous container**. An instance
>   of array stores N elements of type T, so that size() == N is an
>   invariant.

**Update:** It appears the implementation *might* include the padding.
More info on the subject in these SO posts:
[Is the size of std::array defined by standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103244/is-the-size-of-stdarray-defined-by-standard)
and specifically this answer:
[Is the data in nested std::arrays guaranteed to be contiguous?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9762710/8202288)

Comment: Ha, so simple.. `array` contiguously places N blocks of contiguous `array` of M elements, but for some reasons I was scaried to think that Array2D will be contiguous. Thank you. The question about iterators left

Comment: @MrPisarik: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9762712/8157187) contradicts. Maybe something has changed in C++14?

Comment: @geza If every element in an array is contiguous then every array in an array is placed next to each other. The standard is pretty clear on this one.

Comment: @Ron: It is guaranteed, if there is no padding at the end of an `std::array`. I don't know what the standard says about this. But I bet a sane implementation would not do any padding there (but the possibility still there, if the standard doesn't prohibit this).

Comment: The problem is that each *individual* array has contiguous content but the gaps *between* different `std::array` elements are undefined. So the *contiguity* of an *array of array* is "lumpy" at best.

Comment: @geza A `std::array` can have padding at the end.