# What is the memory layout of vector of arrays?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, stdvector, stdarray

can anybody explaine the memory layout of

```
std::vector<std::array<int, 5>> vec(2)
```

does it provide contiguous memory block of a 2D array
with 2 rows of 5 elements?

To my understanding, the vector of vectors

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec(2, std::vector<int>(5))
```

provide the memory layout of **two** *contiguous arrays of length* **5 element**s *in different locations* in memory.

Will it be the same for the vector of arrays?

Comment: Given the answers, if you want this, use `std::vector<int> vec(5*2)` and do 2D indexing yourself inside the flat 1D array.  Maybe write a wrapper class for 2D indexing on top of a flat container, with either a templated or runtime-variable row length.  You'd also want to expose a flat view so algorithms that just need to do something to every element without caring about 2D position can do that with one big loop, more efficiently.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Arrays do not have any indirection, but just store their data "directly". That is, a `std::array<int, 5>` literally contains five `int`s in a row, flat. And, like vectors, they do not put padding between their elements, so they're "internally contiguous".

However, [the `std::array` object itself may be larger than the set of its elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9762712/560648)! It is permitted to have trailing "stuff" like padding. So, although likely, it is not necessarily true that your data will *all* be contiguous in the first case.

```
An int
+----+
|    |
+----+

A vector of 2 x int
+----+----+----+-----+        +----+----+
| housekeeping | ptr |        | 1  |  2 |
+----+----+----+-----+        +----+----+
                   |          ^
                   \-----------

An std::array<int, 5>
+----+----+----+----+----+----------->
| 1  |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 | possible cruft/padding....
+----+----+----+----+----+----------->

A vector of 2 x std::array<int, 5>
+----+----+----+-----+        +----+----+----+----+----+----------------------------+----+----+----+----+----+----------->
| housekeeping | ptr |        | 1  |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 | possible cruft/padding.... | 1  |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 | possible cruft/padding....
+----+----+----+-----+        +----+----+----+----+----+----------------------------+----+----+----+----+----+----------->
                   |          ^
                   \-----------
```

And, even if it were, due to aliasing rules, whether you'd be able to use a single `int*` to navigate all 10 numbers would potentially be a different matter!

All in all, a vector of ten `int`s would be clearer, completely packed, and possibly safer to use.

In the case of a vector of vectors, a vector is really just a pointer plus some housekeeping, hence the indirection (as you say).

Comment: According to the answers here data don't have to be contiguous: [Is the data in nested std::arrays guaranteed to be contiguous?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9762662/580083). There are some discussion about this topic. Another discussions: [Does std::array of std::array have contiguous memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47120994/580083) and [Is the size of std::array defined by standard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19103244/580083).

Comment: IOW, while the memory allocated has to be contiguous, the array elements need not be.

Comment: Ooh this answer just gets posher and posher. Upped to 13.

Comment: @Bathsheba The diagram is appalling but oh well 

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If you add a diagram for a vector of vectors, your answer will be "craved into stone" :)

Comment: @DanielLangr Bah maybe later 

Comment: Note `static_assert(sizeof(std::array<int,t>)==sizeof(int)*5)` mitigates any padding (and passes in every version of every major compiler that has supported `std::array`).  It does not mitigate against aliasing issues.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont After much consideration I would _probably_ consider this sufficient, given how widely it will pass. But a vector of ints is still better.

Answer (score 19):

The big difference between `std::vector` and `std::array` is that `std::vector` contains a pointer to the memory it wraps, while `std::array` contains the actual array in itself.

That means a vector of vectors is like a [jagged array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array).

For a vector of arrays, the `std::array` objects will be placed contiguously but separate from the vector object. Note that the `std::array` object themselves may be larger than the array they contain, and if so then the data will not be contiguous.

The last bit also means that an array (plain C-style or `std::array`) of `std::array` may also not keep the data contiguously. The `std::array` objects in the array will be contiguous, but not the data.

The only way to guarantee contiguous data for a "multi-dimensional" array is nested plain C-style arrays.

Comment: _It also means that a vector of arrays is similar to an array of arrays, in that the data is all contiguous..._ I dare to disagree. Please, see my comment under LightnessRacesinOrbit's answer.

Comment: @DanielLangr Thanks for reminding me. Rephrased that part.

Answer (score 12):

The C++ standard does not guarantee that `std::array` doesn't contain any payload at the end of the array, so alas you cannot assume that the first element of a subsequent array is just after the last element of a prior array.

Even if that were the case, the behaviour on attempting to reach any element in a array by pointer arithmetic on a pointer to an element in a different array is undefined. This is because pointer arithmetic is only valid within arrays.

The above also applies to a `std::array<std::array>`.

Answer (score 6):

```
static_assert(sizeof(std::array<int,5>)==5*sizeof(int));
```

the above mitigates against having any padding on the end of a `std::array`.  No major compiler will cause the above to fail to this date, and I'd bet won't in the future.

If and only if the above fails, then `std::vector<std::array<int,5>> v(2)` will have a "gap" between the `std::array`s.

This doesn't help as much as you'd like; a pointer generated as follows:

```
int* ptr = &v[0][0];
```

only has a domain of validity up to `ptr+5`, and dereferencing `ptr+5` is undefined behavior.

This is due to aliasing rules; you aren't allowed to "walk" past the end of one object into another, even if you know it is there, unless you first round-trip to certain types (like `char*`) where less restricted pointer arithmetic is permitted.

That rule, in turn, exists to allow compilers to reason about what data is being accessed through which pointer, without having to prove that arbitrary pointer arithmetic will let you reach outside objects.

So:

```
struct bob {
  int x,y,z;
};

bob b {1,2,3};
int* py = &b.y;
```

no matter what you do with `py` as an `int*`, you *cannot* legally modify `x` or `z` with it.

```
*py = 77;
py[-1]=3;
std::cout << b.x;
```

the complier can optimize the `std::cout` line to simply print `1`, because the `py[-1]=3` may *attempt* to modify `b.x`, but doing so through that means is undefined behavior.

The same kind of restrictions prevent you from going from the first array in your `std::vector` to the second (ie, beyond `ptr+4`).

Creating `ptr+5` is legal, but only as a one-past-the-end pointer.  Comparing `ptr+5 == &v[1][0]` is also not specified in result, even though their binary values are absolutely going to be identical in every compiler on every major hardware system.

If you want to go futher down the rabbit hole, it isn't even possible to implement `std::vector<int>` within C++ itself due to these restrictions on pointer aliasing.  Last I checked (which was before [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), but I didn't see a resolution in C++17) the standard committee was working on solving this, but I don't know the state of any such effort.  (This is less of a problem than you might think, because nothing requires that `std::vector<int>` be implemented in standard-compliant C++; it must simply have standard-defined behavior.  It can use compiler-specific extensions internally.)

Comment: Nice answer; upped. Note also the somewhat related issue that you can’t write malloc in standard C.