# Is there a maximum number of std::map inside a std::map in c++?

Tags: c++, vector, dictionary

I need to create a map containing a map that has a map as value etc.

I would like to ask if there is a limitation in terms of max complexity in this.

I have this `std::map<string,std::map<string,std::map<string,vector<double>>>> BaselineData;`

but even if i insert the data like this nothing is inserted `BaselineData.insert(std::pair<string,map<string,map<string,vector<double>>>>("A String",Spacedata));`
Where `Spacedata` is `map<string,map<string,vector<double>>> Spacedata;`

Thank you in advance

Solved: Finally it was my bad, everything was correct apart from the fact that the debugger in VS is stuck and can't show the content, probably due to the multidimensional mapping.

Comment: No. Unless the compiler runs out of memory... Could you give a more complete example?

Comment: How did you check that nothing was inserted?

Comment: Unless you need the individual maps for something, you may have better luck creating a structure with 3 strings and a comparison operator and using that as the key for a single layer `map`. Or even [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple).

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23601686/shorthand-syntax-for-c-map-in-map/23601853#23601853

Comment: @WernerHenze i run at debug so is checked that the previous map Spacedata is created and initialised properly...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's up to the compiler whether to impose limits on the number or recursive depth of template arguments. C++11 suggests a limit of at least 1024 - but that's just advisory. In any case, your type doesn't come close to any limit that a reasonable compiler would impose.

Your code works for me, when I assemble the fragments into a test case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::map<string,std::map<string,std::map<string,vector<double>>>> BaselineData;
    map<string,map<string,vector<double>>> Spacedata;
    BaselineData.insert(std::pair<string,map<string,map<string,vector<double>>>>("A String",Spacedata));

    std::cout << BaselineData.count("A String") << '\n';    
}
```

Output: 1

Demo: http://ideone.com/TqBeGA

If you're still having trouble, please post a complete test case to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Finally it was my bad, everything was correct apart from the fact that the debugger in VS is stuck and can't show the content, probably due to the multidimensional mapping.