# C++: Define map with values of recursive nature

Tags: c++, dictionary

I'd like to define a map that it takes a string as a key, but the value would be a map again with string as the key, but the value would be a map of the similar nature,..., eventually the last map in the chain would be a map of from string to string.

I'm trying to implement the JSON data structure of the tag to value.

To illustrate, here are the code segments that I could come up:

```
typedef map<string, string> str2str;
typedef map<string, str2str> str2str2str;
...
typedef map<string, str2map_or_str> str2map_or_str;
```

What's the idiomatic approach in C++?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23601686/shorthand-syntax-for-c-map-in-map. Perhaps that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but that solution seems to assume the known level of the maps. I don't know before hand, how many levels it requires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simplistic approach would be to use a `struct` that has a `string` and a recursive `map`.

```
struct ParseData;
using MapValue = std::map<std::string, ParseData>;

struct ParseData
{
   std::string string_value;
   MapValue map_value;
};
```

Then, you can capture the parsed data using either a `ParseData` object or a `MapValue` object.

Comment: Isn't the value type of `std::map` required to be complete? boost jumps through many hoops to accomplish the recursive definition. Otherwise this would be the obvious approach.

Comment: @StoryTeller, I am not sure. Seems to work at https://ideone.com/gmTBWB.

Comment: @StoryTeller, push comes to shove, one can use `MapValue*` in `ParseData` for `map_value`.

Comment: You should add the (smart) pointer solution to your answer. That's the well defined, no library solution I believe.

Comment: @StoryTeller, strangely enough, `shared_ptr` requires a complete type.

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted. Thanks @StoryTeller for verification! Following your example, I tried to add retrieval code, but I ran into data corruption problem. I wonder if you could take a look at my code at https://ideone.com/KdPecq#comments

Comment: @YuShen, the problem with the code is that you are using the variable `p` in the for loop. As a consequence, it just contains a `string` at the end of the for loop. You can reassign `parseData3_1` to `p` after the loop to get predictable behavior.

Comment: @RSahu, thanks for reviewing it for me. I thought that it would at the end result in still a ParseData instant, but with only string_value to have valid value. I'll take second look.  I also noticed by debugging in the loop when it executes to look up for "e", the resulted result is already corrupted, before reaching the last key looking up.

Answer (score 3):

The more idiomatic solution IMO is to use a library that allows for recursive type definitions. You essentially want a tree where each leaf is just a string. Thankfully, [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/variant.html) allows you to define recursive variants:

```
using map_data = boost::make_recursive_variant<
                   std::string, 
                   std::map<
                     std::string, 
                     boost::recursive_variant_
                   >
                 >::type;
```

This is a utility meta function that defines a new variant type. It will either be a simple `std::string` or a `std::map` of `std::string` to `map_data` (marked with the special tag `boost::recursive_variant_`). And that's it. No depth limitation.

Then your json_data type is simply the following alias:

```
using json_data = std::map<std::string, map_data>;
```

You can see it live over [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/633273d034816a73). The only caveat is that you'll need to rewrite your code to use the `boost::variant` visitor pattern. But that isn't too difficult an exercise. I daresay the recursive nature of the definition makes the logic almost write itself.